# hive distributed query to join data from on-primise hadoop cluster and amazon s3 hadoop cluster

Tags: amazon-data-pipeline

I have certain amount of data in on-primise hadoop cluster(in my local network) and I have certain amount of data in Amazon cloud S3 hadoop cluster. in both places my data resides in hive tables.

I want to fire a hive query from my local hadoop cluster, this query should join the data from my local cluster hive table and hive table data from amazon s3 hadoop cluster. It should join data from both places and give results

to my local cluster env as I am firing a query from my local hive shell.

Does this problem can be handled by Amazon Data Pipeline. If yes,Please guide me the way.

Thanks, -Suyodha

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no automatic solution.

First you have to export your data from your on-premise cluster and transfer it to S3 on AWS.  Then you can load this data into EMR cluster.

You can use Data Pipeline to execute a Hive Activity on the data set transmitted to S3.

Out of the box activities in Data Pipeline help with S3 copy, EMR cluster setup and Hive activity execution.  They wont help with transferring your data from on-premise to AWS.  If you have to automate that, you will need to write code some scripts etc.

Comment: It is possible with Attunity CloudBean. I am looking in to. I will come back to you as soon as possible. Thanks a lot for looking into it.